# Split server command output to next line

Tags: bash

I am preparing a bash script, where i am using "pssh" to run command on 1000+ servers (saved in /tmp/hosts)

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i "uname;date"

[1] 13:10:56 [FAILURE] SERVER1 Exited with error code 255
Stderr: @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@       WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The ECDSA host key for SERVER1 has changed,
and the key for the corresponding IP address 10.238.36.42
has a different value. This could either mean that.............
......................
[2] 13:10:56 [SUCCESS] SERVER2
Linux
Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[3] 13:10:56 [SUCCESS] SERVER3
Linux
Fri Jan 25 13:10:56 CET 2019
[4] 13:10:56 [SUCCESS] SERVER4
Linux
Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[5] 13:10:56 [SUCCESS] SERVER5
Linux
Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[6] 13:10:56 [SUCCESS] SERVER6
Linux
Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
```

I am Expecting the output as below, with suppressing the warnings if there is any

```
[FAILURE], SERVER1, Exited with error code 255
[SUCCESS], SERVER2,Linux,Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER3,Linux,Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER4,Linux,Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER5,Linux,Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER6,Linux,Fri Jan 25 12:10:56 UTC 2019
[FAILURE], HOST1, Exited with error code 255
[FAILURE], HOST2, Exited with error code 255
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really 100% sure what you're asking but it sounds like the following might work for you:

```
# What you get
$ uname; date
Linux
Fri 25 Jan 13:09:13 GMT 2019

# What you want
$ echo "$(uname), $(date)"
Linux, Fri 25 Jan 13:09:42 GMT 2019
```

So your command would be:

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo "$(uname), $(date)"'
```

(please note the use of single quotes - this is important so your local shell doesn't expand the process subshells)

What this does is it runs `uname` and `date` as a subshell and returns the result as a variable which is dropped into the `echo` command. As described above:

```
echo "$(uname), $(date)"
# expands as
echo Linux, Fri 25 Jan 13:10:57 GMT 2019
```

As an aside, I'm not all that familiar with pssh. I'm assuming it just runs whatever $SHELL your user has defined on the remote servers `/etc/group` file (or whatever your shared authentication server is). If not, the above trick may not work. However I would recommend looking into another system for managing your fleet of servers. eg Ansible might suit you given your tendency to use SSH.

---

**edit: OK, I'm now understanding some of the additional requirements.**

If you only want the first line of the failure, then you could grep that out:

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo "$(uname), $(date)"' | grep -Eo '\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\].*$'
```

(`-E` is for extended regexp support so you can have the `(SUCCESS|FAILURE)`. `-o` will only return the matching pattern rather than the entire line.

If you really needed a comma then you could additionally pipe that into `sed`:

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo "$(uname), $(date)"' | egrep -o '\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\].*$' | sed -r 's:(\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\]):\1,:'
```

(I've used the `:` character in the `sed` example above because I think it's a little more readable so you can see what it is doing. However you can replace that with the more typical `/` character if you want)

What this does is look for `[SUCCESS]` or `[FAILURE]` then returns that string (via `\1` back reference) plus a comma.

Example:

```
$ echo -e "sdfsdfsdf[FAILURE] $(uname), $(date)\nsdfsdf\nasdfsdf" | grep -Eo '\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\].*$' | sed -r 's:(\[(SUCCESS|FAILURE)\]):\1,:'
[FAILURE], Linux, Fri 25 Jan 16:15:03 GMT 2019
```

If for any reason you can return something other than `[SUCCESS]` and `[FAILURE]` then the code can (ironically) be shortened further with `[A-Z]+`:

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i 'echo "$(uname), $(date)"' | egrep -o '\[[A-Z]+\].*$' | sed -r 's:(\[[A-Z]+\]):\1,:'
```

But I suggest you stick with the `(SUCCESS|FAILURE)` version for now just in case `[A-Z]+` returns some false positives.

Answer (score 0):

Well thanks to @Imorg you can use:

```
pssh -h /tmp/hosts -i "uname;date"  | grep -o \[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*\].* | sed -Ee 's/(^\[FAILURE\]) (SERVER[0-9]*) (.*)/\1, \2, \3/g' -Ee 's/(^\[SUCCESS\]) (.*)/\1, \2,'"$(uname)"','"$(date)"'/g'
```

So, `grep -o \[[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]*\].*` will give output as:

```
[FAILURE] SERVER1 Exited with error code 255
[SUCCESS] SERVER2
[SUCCESS] SERVER3
[SUCCESS] SERVER4
[SUCCESS] SERVER5
[SUCCESS] SERVER6
```

And `sed -Ee 's/(^\[FAILURE\]) (SERVER[0-9]*) (.*)/\1, \2, \3/g'`,`between strings containing`FAILURE` and SERVER and between EXITED.

And `sed -Ee 's/(^\[SUCCESS\]) (.*)/\1, \2,'"$(uname)"','"$(date)"'/g'` will add `,` between first two words and will add `,output of uname command, output of date command`.

So final output will look like:

```
[FAILURE], SERVER1, Exited with error code 255
[SUCCESS], SERVER2,Linux,Fri Jan 25 19:27:30 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER3,Linux,Fri Jan 25 19:27:30 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER4,Linux,Fri Jan 25 19:27:30 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER5,Linux,Fri Jan 25 19:27:30 UTC 2019
[SUCCESS], SERVER6,Linux,Fri Jan 25 19:27:30 UTC 2019
```

Comment: @Sin15 updated answer.

Comment: It will work with any name of the form `SERVER***`

Comment: @Sin15 just give some examples i will modify accordingly.

Comment: Most of the names are totally different.
Actually i have to send the data to excel file, so every columns should have ","
For Success -> 4 columns
For Failure -> 3 columns